# Is there a way I can parse dates where I can determine what day I want?

Tags: java, json, datetime, gson

I am making a discord bot and the values for 'XP' change daily, as in they change with the date. Is there a way I can get the date and have it -1, -2, etc? I need to get the values for the past week.

Comment: Here is an example,
```"expHistory": {
"2020-10-11": 0,
"2020-10-10": 0,
"2020-10-09": 14544,
"2020-10-08": 4095,
"2020-10-07": 9894,
"2020-10-06": 1208,
"2020-10-05": 0
}```

Comment: It looks like the type of `expHistory` could be expressed as `Map<LocalDate, Int>`. If you had such a map, as well as a `date` reference for "today", you could try something like `map.get(date.minusDays(1))`.

Comment: What exactly do you have? Do you have the dates, and want them to be converted to days relative to today, e.g. yesterday = -1, day before yesterday = -2 etc? Or is it the other wsy around?

Comment: Please attach your JSON example and what you expect to achieve explicitly in original question, not in comment.